# calling an automatic popup box through javascript on php condition

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've created a pop up box which is invisible, but upon being targeted it's opacity is increased to one. I want it to pop up if the user is a "firstTimeUser" which is stored in a PHP $_SESSION variable. But can't figure out how to integrate the javascript, which will call the tag and the PHP. I understand that PHP is a server side language and javascript client side, but isn't there a way to call a javascript function based on a php variable?

Here is my attempted integration and below the code for the box:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['firstTimeUser'])){
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location=document.getElementById('bigBoxID');
    </script>
<?php
    }
?>

<div class="outerBox" id="bigBoxID">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2 class="firstTimerFont" style="text-align: center">Salut et bienvenue!</h2>
        <p>Welcome first time user!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And just so you can see, here is the CSS:

```
outerBox{

background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
transition: opacity 0.6s;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 10;
}

.outerBox:target{
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

.popup{ 
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: relative;
padding: 40px;
width: 50%;
z-index: 11;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` returns an array-like object. Use `window.location = '#bigBoxID';` instead.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['firstTimeUser'])){
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location = '#bigBoxID';
    </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to open popup, put by default target as

`visible: hidden`

Then:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php 
$openPopup = (isset($_SESSION['firstTimeUser'])) ? "true": "false";
    echo " var openPopup = $openPopup" ;
?>
    if(openPopup){

$('.popup').show();
    }jquery
</script>
```

I suggest you to use [jquery](https://jquery.com/)